# How to get private data when you're using a initialization list?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm learning OOP in C++ now and I just met a little problem.

How to get private data from the base class in a derived class when you're using list initialization in the base class?

```
class  CPunct
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    CPunct(double a, double b) : x(a), y(b) {}   //initialization list 
};

class CDreapta :public CPunct
{
public: 
    friend void lineFrom2Points(CPunct& a, CPunct& b) // Function to find the line by two points
    {
        double expr1 = b.y - a.y; //expresion 1
        double expr2 = a.x - b.x;  //expresion 2
        double expr3 = expr1 * (a.x) + expr2 * (a.y); //expresion 3

        if (expr2 < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "The line passing through points a and b is: "
                << expr1 << "x " << expr2 << "y = " << expr3 << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "The line passing through points a and b is: "
                << expr1 << "x + " << expr2 << "y = " << expr3 << "\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Here in my code I tried to declare the function (lineFrom2Points) that use private data from the base class CPunct as a friend but it seems like it woundn't work.
Please, give me an advice! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lineFrom2Points` is a friend of `CDreapta`, not `CPunct`. The fact that `CDreapta` inherits from `CPunct`, doesn't make this function a friend of `CPunct`. `CPunct` itself is quite useless. Its data members are `private`, and cannot be accessed even in derived classes. You might want to make them `protected` or add public or protected member functions to access them.

A few examples:

```
class CPunct {
private:
    double x;
    double y;

public:
    CPunct(double a, double b) : x(a), y(b) {}

    friend void lineFrom2Points(CPunct& a, CPunct& b) {
        // can access a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y here
    }
};
```

```
class CPunct {
protected:
    double x;
    double y;

public:
    CPunct(double a, double b) : x(a), y(b) {}
};

class CDreapta : public CPunct {
public: 
    using CPunct::CPunct;  // inherit the CPunct constuctor

    friend void lineFrom2Points(CDreapta& a, CDreapta& b) {
        // can access a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y here
    }
};
```

```
class CPunct {
private:
    double x_;
    double y_;

public:
    CPunct(double a, double b) : x_(a), y_(b) {}

    double x() const { return x_; }
    double y() const { return y_; }
};

class CDreapta : public CPunct {
public:
    using CPunct::CPunct;
};

void lineFrom2Points(CDreapta& a, CDreapta& b) {
    // can access a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y here via x() and y()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help! I didn't know that I can inherit the constructor of the base class :/!

Comment: @Ion, this is C++11 feature. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For such types as CPunct there no point to make its members private. So it's better to redefine this class to struct with public members.

```
struct CPunct
 {
  double x;
  double y;

  CPunct(double x_, double y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
 };
```